# Using Custom Javascript Date Variable with IMG SRC Element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a custom javascript date variable in some `img src` elements on my website but I am having some trouble with it, as the code is not recognizing the `utcdate` variable.. I have decided to use `moment.js` to help me achieve generating the current date (in UTC format). The purpose of this is to drive (and display) images in a gallery that live in a directory that is named with today's date in `YYYYMMDD` format.

**HTML Code:**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

     // set an element
     $("#date").val( moment().format('YYYYMMDD') );

     // set a variable
     var utcdate = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');

});
</script>

<div class="gallery" align="center">
    <h1>Title Goes Here</h1>

    <br />

    <div class="thumbnails">
        <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" name="img1" src="http://some.website/somedirectory/" + utcdate + "/someotherdirectory/image.png" alt=""/>
    </div><br/>

    <div class="preview" align="center">
        <img name="preview" src="http://some.website/somedirectory/" + utcdate + "/someotherdirectory/image.png" alt=""/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle answer](https://jsfiddle.net/myselfdesai/gbbh0jup/)

```
 var utcdate = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
 $("#my_image").attr("src","http://some.website/somedirectory/" + utcdate + "/someotherdirectory/image.png");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the images are not displaying. I went and checked the URLs and it appears that only the first section `http://some.website/somedirectory/` of my URL is being passed outside of the javascript code.